# On the derivatives of the solutions of the heat equations with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, parabolic-pde, regularity

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth domain with compact closure.  More precisely, $\Omega$ is a $C^\infty$ domain. We write $\partial \Omega$ for the boundary of $\Omega$, and denote by $n$ the inward unit normal vector of $\partial \Omega.$
We now consider the following heat equation equation with the Neumann boundary condition.

\begin{align*}
\left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(t,x)&=\Delta u(t,x),\quad (t,x)\in(0,\infty)\times \Omega,\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial n} u(t,x)&=0,\quad (t,x) \in (0,\infty)\times \partial \Omega,\\
u(0,x)&=f(x),\quad x \in \overline{\Omega}.
    \end{alignedat}
    \right.
\end{align*}

We write $(P_tf)(x)=u(t,x)$.

We know that if the initial data $f$ is a continuous function on $\overline{\Omega}$, for any $t>0$, the solution $(P_tf)(x)$ belongs to $C^2(\overline{\Omega}):=C^2(\mathbb{R}^d)|_{\Omega}$. See [[SU](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-mathematics-of-kyoto-university/volume-4/issue-3/Multi-dimensional-diffusion-and-the-Markov-process-on-the-boundary/10.1215/kjm/1250524605.full), Theorem 2.1, (i)] for example.

We assume in addition that $\Omega$ is a convex domain. Then, from the proof of [[FL](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.1965.pdf),Theorem 1.2] we can find a positive constant $C>0$ such that for every $f \in C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ and $t \in (0,1]$,
\begin{align}
\sup_{x \in \overline{\Omega}}|D (P_tf)(x)|  \le \sup_{x \in \overline{\Omega}}| (Df)(x)|. \tag{A}
\end{align}

**Questions.**
I am interested in an estimate than similar to ${\rm (A)}$. Let $f$ be sufficiently  smooth function on $\overline{\Omega}$ [for example, $f$ is a $C^3$ function on $\overline{\Omega}$ ]. Then, for any $t>0$, the solution $P_tf$ is a $C^3$ function on $\overline{\Omega}$?  If so, can we prove the following statement: there exists $C>0$ such that for any $f \in C^3(\overline{\Omega})$ and $t \in (0,1]$, we have \begin{align*}
\| P_tf\|_{C_b^3(\mathbb{R}^d)} \le C\|f\|_{C_b^3(\mathbb{R}^d)}.
\end{align*}
Here, we define $\|f\|_{C_b^3(\mathbb{R}^d)}=\sum_{|\alpha|\le 3}\|D^\alpha f\|_\infty$ [$\alpha$ is a multi index and $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the sup-norm]. Such an estimate can be found in some literature, but not immediately in the case of the Neumann semigroup.

Comment: This result should be here: F. Colombo, V. Vespri "GENERATION OF ANALYTIC SEMIGROUPS IN $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$  AND $C^k(\Omega)$", Differential and Integral Equations Volume 9, Number 2, March 1996, pp. 421 – 436. There is also a reference to an older result by Mora, inside.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you very much for your comment. I am always grateful to you.